# Obtener solo 2 decimales

Tags: angularjs

tengo el siguiente js:

```
var array = ["paco", "185.6687", "lucas", "1365.2541"]

<div ng-repeat="val in array">
   {{val}}
</div>
```

Se que si fuese número con que haga `{{val | number:2}}` funcionaria pero si tengo ese array, ¿Cómo hago para que esos caso solo me muestre 2 decimales?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de AngularJS estás usando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Angular puedes crear una función que dé formato, y entonces en lugar de directamente darle salida a la variable, darle salida a la función que da formato (pasándole la variable como parámetro de entrada).

En tu caso particular, quieres una función que si la entrada es una cadena la deje como tal, pero si es un número sólo deje dos decimales. Esto se podría hacer con una simple función:

```
function formateaValor(valor) {
  // si no es un número devuelve el valor, o lo convierte a número con 2 decimales
  return isNaN(valor) ? valor : parseFloat(valor).toFixed(2);
}
```

Eso lo puedes integrar en AngularJS de la siguiente manera:

```js
var app = angular.module("miApp", []);
app.controller("miCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.array = ["paco", "185.6687", "lucas", "1365.2541"];
  $scope.miFormato = function(valor) {
    return isNaN(valor) ? valor : parseFloat(valor).toFixed(2);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="miApp" ng-controller="miCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="val in array">
    {{ miFormato(val) }}
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var n1 = array[1].toFixed(2);
var n2 = array[3].toFixed(2);
```

Asi solo te pillara 2 decimales.

```
for(int i = 0;i < array[].length;i++){
 if(array[i].isNaN(array[i])) {
    array[i] = array[i].toFixed(2);
  }else{

 }
}
```

Algo asi me suena que igual te puede funcionar

Comment: esta opcion no me vale porque el array puede ser N y las posiciones variables

Comment: siempre va a ser nombre, numero, nombre numero?

Comment: no, puede ser numero, numero, nombre o todas las combinaciones, nada fijo

Comment: Prueba eso ultimo, basicamente es un if, si no es texto, hace el fixed, si no lo es, pasa de ello PD: en teoria, igual falla algo

Comment: gracias, es una opcion, lo malo es que el array ya me viene asi, entonces con lo que me propones son 2 for, uno en el js para recorrer el array y otro en la vista(hmtl), cuando solo me gustaria hacerlo en el html

Comment: Pues me parece que es la unica manera, lo unico qie en el bucle del html, pongas el if directamente, pero no creo que se pueda :S